# What is your preferred size and number of monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Do you like to have a single giant monitor, a couple mid-sized monitors or some other configuration? Specifically, I’m interested in your home general purpose computer system.  (No media centers or netbooks)

Comment: Switched this topic to CW because it is inviting more open-ended discussion.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to remember that for appropriate questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3x 21 inches. It gives you a clear "primary" monitor to work on with a couple of secondary monitors to integrate with. Too much more than 21" and it is hard to fit it on a desk.

Comment: I assume these are 4:3 monitors which you can't find any more.

Answer (score 2):

At home I have two 22" widescreen LCDs.

At work I have three (perhaps a little overkill).

Answer (score 1):

I have one 22'' monitor with Full HD - 1920x1080. Most 22'' do not offer such resolution, but some manufactures create such. At work I have two 1280x1024 monitors, but I found one big monitor more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to have three 1280x1024s, but for space and pocketbook reasons I have one 1280x1024 and one 1024 x 768 at home at the moment.

I'm probably in the minority in that I'm not a huge fan of going larger than 1280x1024. Any larger than that and I start having to do desktop window management instead of just maximizing everything. Kind of a pain.

All widescreen desktop monitors need to die in a fire.

Answer (score 1):

- at least 3 monitors
- no smaller than 19" diagonal
- no smaller resolution than 1280x1024

This leaves quite a bit of possibilities out there.  Widescreen is a plus, if you can get a desk to accommodate the additional space needed.  It's also a setup that is within reasonable reach of mom-and-pop, i.e. it's a realistic goal that can be achieved by them if they want it.  Spending thousands for ultra-high-end monitors is nice but frankly not everyone can plunk down that kind of money, especially if they have a house, kids, cars, cards, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Recent videos:
 - [Stretched video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSjv84WXiSg&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fzi255%2Ecom%2FPost%2Easpx%3FTitle%3DWin7%2BMagnifier%2B%252B%2BMultimon%2B%253D%2BSupermassive%2Bvideo&feature=player_embedded)
 - [Stretched game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16-Xh6Rup8w&feature=channel_page)

My [rig](http://kconnolly.net/Post.aspx?Title=New+Dell+2208WFP+Monitors1):

[image]

Still looking. Current plan is six 22" widescreens side by side in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have this fantasy of having a 30" (2650x1600) flanked by a pair of 20" 4:3 (1600x1200) rotated into portrait mode.

At work I have a 20" 16:9 1680x1050 + 17" 4:3 1280x1024, and it's not nearly enough pixels.

Comment: I've had that configuration for a few years now.  Outside of gaming, it's great 99% of the time: the remainder I wish had had 2nd 30" to put 2 big windows side by side.  Gaming is a minor disappointment since none of the multimonitor tools place nicely with a PLP layout.  http://orthogonaltonormal.com/midden/NewYearsResolution_4960x1600.jpg

Comment: @DanNeely: Jealous!  :-D

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of personal taste, however one thing I have found extremely useful over the years is to set aside a single monitor (preferably widescreen) rotated into portrait mode exclusively to read ebooks and pdf documents from.

It comes in especially handy if you are a developer and are reading a computer ebook on one monitor and trying out the examples in your IDE on the other.

Answer (score 0):

x2 at 24". Oh, and 1920x1200 minimum or bust. No point having them that large unless they support a good resolution.

Having them both height adjustable is also nice. We have one developer here at work that has dual-24"s but are sitting on two cooking pots to so they are higher.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what I am doing.  At home for email and web surfing a MacBook Pro with a 15" screen is plenty. At work a 23" Cinema display (1650X1080) and a 24"(1900X1200) Dell are adequate for writing software all day.  For work I don't think I could go back to a single monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I should add in my own thoughts on this.

Number: 4

Size: 20"- 22" (going for 22" in the future)

Layout: Upside down T (3 on bottom row, one above)

Answer (score 0):

My preferences are, in order:

1) Multiple large monitors (2-3) (for example, any size apple cinema display)

2) multiple smallish identical (2-4) high contrast 1600x1200 or better monitors

3) a single large monitor (cinema display size)

I like multiple screens for gaming, or be able to dedicate different screens to different things (like VMWare sessions or video)

Answer (score 0):

I have three monitors side by side, don't know the exact measurements and I'm too lazy to do that.

They are the same height and only the one in the middle is wide. Sometimes, I will arrange that same screen vertically when I'm leading with large chunks of code.