# does 2nd video card have to be the same

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run two separate video cards?](https://superuser.com/questions/15587/is-it-possible-to-run-two-separate-video-cards)

I have one PCIe slot in my [Gateway GM5260](http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/R/1009212/1009212sp2.shtml) running Vista (also have XP Pro available)

I have 2 PCIe cards available both have multi-outputs

1. NVIDIA GeForce™ 7300LE PCIe
2. ASUS EAH4350

I was wondering if I can add a 2nd PCI video card to give me support for up to 4 monitors? What are the caveats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning on doing SLI, you should be alright with two different cards. The only thing to watch for is that you have a sufficient power supply.

Comment: While it's not essential it would make life a lot easier if they used the same driver