# Best way to setup multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I currently have 5 displays. The following is how I installed them.

1. Three 19'' for workspace. One of them is connect directly to the graphic card via DVI. Two of them are using usb graphic adapters.
2. One 720 projector - directly connect to the graphic card via DVI.
3. One 30'' dell monitor - currently connect to laptop via VGA.

I would like to connect 30' dell to my main computer.

I do not game or use graphic applications.

What would be my best options? I am thinking to buy two  lower-performance ati or nvidia cards and install them as crossfire(???) or sli. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: see some ideas here: http://superuser.com/questions/9034/multi-monitor-usage

Answer (score 2):

Yes, two lower performance cards would be fine. Just ensure that they are the same model so you can utilize the same driver for both. When you start using different models is where things get fuzzy. Windows doesn't really like when you have 2 different video drivers installed and it can be very problematic.

I'd also check out the [multimon compatibility database](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/db.asp) to assist you in video card selection.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Matrox [dualhead2go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/) or [triplehead2go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/)

They are external adaptors that lets you connect 2 or 3 monitors in one dvi-port.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dual Graphics cards sounds right.

SLI or Crossfire will provide a nice performance boost.

BTW, why all of the monitors if you're not doing anything graphics intensive?

EDIT: JohnT is right, identical cards work best for SLI/Crossfire.

Comment: programming, perhaps.

Comment: Indeedy. Sounds right. *iPhone development on 13" MacBook != fun* Too small screen and the keyboard shortcuts are weird for this "PC" ->

Comment: @John T // I use three  19'' for programming. I used to use dell 30'', but the resolution is too high for me. So I am using it for video game or TV series. I use projector for movies obviously.

Comment: . I understand that the the 13" MacBook isn't ideal for programming: but doesn't the iPhone have an even *smaller* screen?  =D

Comment: @Warren - +1 for humor, but seriously, I'm not **coding** on the iPhone... Although, I heard about the `iPhone Classic`, which is thrice the size of the iPhone. That might be about as good as a MacBook... (Okay, the iPhone, iPad jokes are no funny anymore.)