# What can I do with two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-monitor Usage](https://superuser.com/questions/9034/multi-monitor-usage)

So I got a new monitor from the [SuperUser Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1342/super-contest-winners-week-1) and it basically screams of power after using a netbook for the past three or so months. I hooked it up to my Dell D620 on a table and grabbed a copy of DisplayFusion, which I set up.

So now I'm wondering, what else can I do with this thing?

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything similar in search.)

Comment: Congrats on winning in the contest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch a movie / tv show on one, work on the other :)

Answer (score 4):

(assuming Windows)

[Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). Now. Set it so there's a separate taskbar for each monitor, and that only windows from that window show up on that taskbar.

[This little app](http://ddmm.sourceforge.net/) brings back Fitts' Law "infinite screen edges" to your multiple monitors. Makes it a lot easier to hit scrollbars, tabs, taskbars, etc. without accidentaly going into the other monitor instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you get more space, better for multitasking. I especially like to have something I'm working on on the first monitor and hulu on the second monitor. [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) is a good utility for multimonitor support.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you do:

Open spreadsheet on one, wordprocessor on other, transfer info.  Open programming editor on one, open command prompt on other and run program while stepping through.  Open whatever on one and ebook on other to learn new things.  Dual monitors are an enormous improvement.